# Can't connect to local website on a specific device

Tags: networking, local-area-network, website

I've created a website which I host on a home server in my local network. When I'm not in my local network I can access the website with the external IP address and the domain. When I'm in my local network this also works for every device **except** of one device. There I can't access the website. I also can't connect via ssh, which works for other devices.

The only difference is, that this device is connected via ethernet but I don't think that this could be a possible reason. I tried to connect to my Wi-Fi but the signal is too low to connect and it's a desktop pc, so I can't test if it would work if the device would be connected to Wi-Fi.

Any help appreciated!